# Online job application through job application engine Recruitee but no confirmation email

Tags: job-offer, applications, online

In the past I applied to multiple jobs using the engine Recruitee. As per my experience, every single time the application was submitted I promptly got a confirmation email.

However today I applied to the position and still some hours latter no confirmation email. After submitting the application there was a confirmation screen. i.e. they application was indeed submitted.

I am however worried that I did not type my email correctly and they company won't be able to reach me. i.e. if they happen to contact me back I will not get their message and they will think I am not interested in the job.

I want to avoid by any means to resubmit my application or try to contact them by other means as I want to avoid they feel harassed.

I also double checked my email is working correctly and I do not have anything in the spam folder.

Questions:
 * Do you know guys if it could happen that even my email address being correct, they disabled sending a confirmation email? i.e. is that possible at all? In the past all my applications through Recruitee had a confirmation email.
 * Is there anyway to confirm if my email address submitted is correct, without having to bother the company?

Comment: Is it possible to check your job applications from Recruitee's website and verify you wrote your email correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You would not have applied unless you were a viable candidate for the position.

The employer needs to hire somebody. So they won't mind a followup. Don't worry too much about harassing them with just one followup.

Ten followups, no. That's harassing them.

Also, you might ask somebody in customer support for the hiring web site about whether you should expect an email reply from them.

Comment: I ask the support. Unfortunately they claim they can't do anything for me.